# instantiate a child when parent is instantiated

Tags: php, wordpress

Can I instantiate a child when when the parent is instantiated?

I am trying to use inheritance to override a parent function.  But I can't just create a new instance of the child because the variable for the parent constructor are not present at the time.

Basically, I am trying to extend a Wordpress plugin and I do not want to change the core plugin files.  When the plugin calls for the parent object to be created, I want the the child to instantiate when that happens to override one of the parent functions.

Example:

```
return new WC_Subscription( $subscription_id );
```

My class extends WC_Subscription, and My class does one thing and that is override one function through inheritance.

Comment: Why don't you replace the WC_Subscription() by yourChildClass() in the code ?

Comment: Because I don't want to override original plugin code... so updates won't screw everything up.

Comment: I think you can instantiate your plugin like a regular class in your page content and then decorate it with your method. Docs about [wp plugin instance](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/70055/best-way-to-initiate-a-class-in-a-wp-plugin) and about [the decorator design pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/decorator/php).